# Using $filter in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have built out an Angular directive to display a D3 visualization. I make use of `$filter` within the `tickFormat` function on my y-axis like so:

```
ySalesAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .orient('left')
  .ticks(6)
  .scale(ySalesScale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return $filter('formatSalesValue')(d.value, 'USD');
  });
```

The problem I'm seeing is that none of these tick labels appear when the page first loads. Indeed if I `console.log($filter('formatSalesValue')(d.value, 'USD'))` I get 6 `undefined` (since my `ticks` property is set to 6). However, as soon as I take an action, clicking within the brush filter for example, the tick labels appear properly formatted.

[image]

My `formatSalesValue` filter calls a service (async operation) because there are dozens of currencies cycling into and out of the system, details of which I retrieve from a DB. I am sure this is the reason my tick labels are undefined. What can I do to make sure these values appear right after page load? Note: I've attempted wrapping my `tickFormat` function in a call to `scope.$apply` but I get a `digest already in progress` error.

Comment: Might be an issue with tickFormat being called outside of a digest cycle.

Comment: If so, add scope.$apply() before your return statement - presuming you are in a directive and the linking function

Comment: Create demo that replicates problem

Comment: See [Replacing d3.js with pure SVG + AngularJS](http://alexandros.resin.io/angular-d3-svg/).

Comment: @dustmouse: Added details to my question. My filter actually makes a service call which I believe is causing this issue.

Comment: What is the return value of `formatSalesValue`. Is it a promise or a number.

Comment: Any way you could put this into a codepen or something? I just tried calling $filter from .tween() and everything seemed to work ok. Is the value d.value in the format that formatSalesValue is expecting?

Comment: As a workaround, use `$timeout` instead of `scope.$apply()`. This will digest and will not throw; and delay a bit.

Comment: post the "formatSalesValue" code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Axis's tickFormat method runs passed callback and uses value returned by it in sync way. That's why you get *undefined* on the first call, as your **$filter** is async.

If this async call is only for performance reasons you should make it sync and look for improvements elsewhere. Should angular watch for so many independent changes it could clog with $digest cycles.

If you make JSBin I probably could tell you more.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

Try using the Angular [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) function.

---

Based on your question, the issue might be any number of things, but this is what I think is the problem:

#### Possible issue

It think that part of the problem is that the what you're getting is happening in a weird bit of the event loop.

[$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) is useful functions because it runs when the current stack is cleared and after n milliseconds have passed, if no time to delay is given, $timeout simply runs as soon as the stack unwinds. It's a useful trick for executing asynchronous code in a single thread.

Using [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) with 0 delay doesn't actually mean the call back will fire-off after zero milliseconds. I just gets executed after a the queue of tasks is processed. Which is when you want to update your labels.

[$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) will actually triggers a digest when it's ready to do so.

#### Possible solution

```
$timeout(function() {
  // Update the label with what comes back from the server
}, 0, false);
```

This is a good video explaining how the Javascript event loop works: [What the heck is the event loop anyway?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)